# Concurrency issue in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a concurrency problem in Java that i'm to able to solve.

I want to set a timeout for a player to write an input and when it's turn is over I set a flag `(player.myTurn)` to false in another thread, which control the game logic, cause I want this thread to stay in the second while and set the timeout to infinity not to catching the `SocketTimeoutException`.

The problem is that after sending the command to the `controllerServerSide` on the last player input, this thread comes back to `inputStream.readObject()` before the variable `myTurn` is modified by the other Thread, so it set again the timeout, and this is a problem for the game.

How can I make this thread to wait until `myTurn` is changed (only over the last player input)?

**ServerThread**

```
public void run(){
    while(!isStopped){
        try {
            while(!player.getMyTurn()){
                socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            }

            socket.setSoTimeout(INPUT_TIMEOUT);
            //ServerThread arrives here 'cause myTurn it isn't changed yet
            String command = (String) inputStream.readObject();

            socket.setSoTimeout(0);

            controllerServerSide.receiveCommand(command);
        }catch (IOException e) {}
```

**GameThread**

```
for(Player player : playerList){

            if(!player.getConnectionState()){

                player.setMyTurn(true);
                //here it starts his turn
                winner = turn.executeTurn(player);
                //here it finish his turn
                player.setMyTurn(false);


                if(winner != null){ 
                    playerList.remove(winner);
                    break;  
                }

            }

}
```

I'm sorry if this is a bad coding style, but I'm practically new to Java.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Maybe read about concurrency in general and the way Java tackles it? Search for "locks/condition variables in Java".

Comment: I've tried a lot of solutions, but it seems that no one of them can solve my problem. Probably i'm placing some construct in the wrong place. Maybe a better solution could be using something else as a timer instead that `socket.setSoTimeout()`?

Comment: You are using "busy waiting" which is most of the time a bad solution. Your problem have a solution...

Comment: Surerly it has a solution, but i can't figure out which one. Can you explain what do you mean by "busy waiting"? 
Edit: Ok i've understand what do you mean by "busy waiting", so it would be better to remove that 
`while(!player.getMyTurn()){
                socket.setSoTimeout(0);
            }` and implement a timer in a different thread?

Comment: This what condvar are for: put your thread in a waiting state until some condition is met...

Comment: I think i'm really close to the solution by using "synchronized block" but there is still something that i don't get.